# Restarting sql servers

Tags: sql-server

Ok I am our only IT guy here and all this was set up by the previous guy. I know pretty much nothing about databases.

We have some software called [E2](https://www.shoptech.com/e2-shop-system/) that keeps track of all our inventory. We also have [centerpoint payroll](https://www.redwingsoftware.com/rwssn/home.aspx?page=329) for our payroll.

We used to restart our server (2k3) whenever E2 was starting to be laggy and sluggish. We would do this by

1. Make everyone get out of E2 as well as everything else open on the server.
2. Restart the server and wait forever for it to show back up.

Well one day I figured out that I could go into the SQL server service manager on the server and hit stop and then start on the AMCO\RWS server and it would have the same effect as a full restart but was a 30 second ordeal rather than 15 minutes plus. Also we only had to have everyone log out of E2 rather than everything.

But now that I think things over I am not sure I am doing right here. I am restarting the AMCO/RWS server for E2 however I am of a passing thought that that may be the database for the payroll software seeing as our payroll is done by RedWing Software. However if i stop that then E2 no longer can connect so they seem to be related somehow. And I can't really tell if anybody is logged into payroll seeing as that person works from home via remote desktop.

Comment: What is AMCO\RWS exactly?

Comment: Here is an image of all i know. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GEynh.png

Comment: That's the name that was given to the instance you're restarting if I recall correctly. My experience with SQL Server 2000 is limited though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be restarting servers to fix sluggishness / latency if you can help it.

If you think the problem is related to the database being the bottleneck, then test for that.
There are some pretty great [free](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) or [not so free](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/) tools out there that can help you diagnose sql server bottlenecks.

However when it comes to finding performance bottlenecks in general, there are books on the subject, and you should probably be utilizing your google-fu to find out where to start. Whatever I can write here will probably not be enough.

Usually to shut down servers you plan [maintenance windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_window). Please stop rebooting during office hours to fix performance issues. You don't know what might be going wrong behind the scenes, and you don't want to end up corrupting your payroll system because it isn't coded properly and you're half committing something.

Comment: If i knew anything about sql I would be looking to google. I don't. Hence why I came here. Telling people that I can't fix the issue is not an option either so not rebooting during office hours is out as well assuming there is not another fix. (We are small. we have one person who uses centerpoint and  about 6 that use E2. Maintenance window for us is "Everyone close out of E2 so that I can restart it.") I have not been having the person using centerpoint close out because i did not realize it might be an issue until recently. If needed I can do so. I am trying to fix my lack of knowledge now.

Comment: @birdman3131 Look into the Brent Ozar link I posted above, they have downloadable free scripts that look at your SQL Server and can help you narrow down what's happening. They have a video tutorial on how to use the scripts if you don't know the first thing about SQL.

Comment: I am looking into it. And sorry if  I sounded a bit annoyed.

Comment: @birdman3131 No problem! I can imagine how frustrated it can be. I would still advise you to tell your users that you can't reboot it during work hours any longer. Maybe something in the lines of `the temporary fix we were using in the past might be causing long-term issues, and we've decided to stop doing it for the time being as we try and find out the root cause`. Perhaps coupled with a weekly reboot of the server? (Depending on how severe the issue is)

Comment: Also I am not sure if it is 2000 we are using because I see references to both 2005 and 2008 sql as well as microsoft sql server with no year. How would i tell which the actual database is on so I can install the proper version of sql management studio to run the brent ozar software? http://i.stack.imgur.com/RUfLg.png is some of what i see. if you need other info just ask.

Comment: @birdman3131 I'm pretty sure it's 2000 seeing as how [service manager was discontinued afaik](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/702b948d-ab45-4269-8f02-decf39569480/where-is-service-manager-in-sql-server-2005?forum=sqltools) But the management studio should be there already. Possibly it's called `Enterprise manager` for sql server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hunch, but given that it is an older ms sql server... and that you can remove sluggishness when you restart the sql server instance, perhaps the issue is a use of temp tables either getting too large and/or not having proper indexes?

If the sluggishness persisted after an sql service restart, i would say it could just be basic SQL bottlnecks (which typically involve optimizing the queries, indexes, and tables used). I am also not entirely sure how ms sql 2000 works in terms of recovery modes and transaction logs, but i would presume it would be similar. Transaction logs build up if the database is in "full" recovery mode, unless you have a maintenance plan that backs up and archives those logs. This might detract from the disk space available for the temporary tables to form.

As far as seeing who is logged on, i believe you can use the SQL management studio (might be called some form of query editor in sql 2000) and run the command "sp_who" or "sp_who2" which will show you the current connections being used by SQL...usually it includes the hostname of the computer who is connected as well.

Comment: 'sp_who' and 'sp_who2' will only show you the direct connections to the database. Depending on how the app functions these might be entirely useless in terms of finding out which employee is logged in or even if they are actively using the application.

Comment: I guess so. any of our ms sql apps always show the host name of the connected party, even if they are using the sql login of the application. I suppose a web based application would pose the biggest problem to using the sp_who commands